# Dynamically pass values to get-winevent

Tags: powershell

I am using the below code to pass values to Get-Winevent, but getting compilation issue, values to be passed only if exist, Please suggest

```
$StartDate  = Read-Date "Enter the start date of the logs, Ex: 17/07/2017 or 17/07/2017 09:00:00"
$EndDate    = Read-Date "Enter the End date of the logs, Ex: 19/07/2017 or 19/07/2017 10:00:00"
$Message    = Read-Host $prompt 'Message/String to search'

if ($StartDate) {
    $params['StartTime'] = $StartDate
}

if ($EndDate) { 
    $params['endtime'] = $EndDate
}

$Event_Logs_Content = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable {@params}
```

Comment: `-FilterHashtable $params`, but you'll need to specify a Log name or a provider as well

Answer (score 0):

This option will list all available log as you can see the asterisk after "-logname", worth to filter to a specific one.

```
$StartDate  = Read-Date "Enter the start date of the logs, Ex: 17/07/2017 or 17/07/2017 09:00:00"
$EndDate    = Read-Date "Enter the End date of the logs, Ex: 19/07/2017 or 19/07/2017 10:00:00"
$Message    = Read-Host $prompt 'Message/String to search'

$StartDate=get-date $StartDate -format "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"
$EndDate=get-date $EndDate -format "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"

$Event_Logs_Content = Get-EventLog -LogName * -After $StartDate -Before $EndDate
```